# Clear created Object memory

Tags: delphi, security, wmi

i'm using `WMI` `SMBios` to get some hardware information

check [uSMBios.pas](https://code.google.com/p/tsmbios/source/browse/trunk/Common/uSMBIOS.pas)

i don't wanna users see what is the used serial numbers in memory so i'm trying to clear it

when i call

```
SMBios:=TSMBios.Create;
//my code
SMBios.free;
```

the SMBios Object still in memory in many locations [image: WinHex]

i tried this code on `Destroy Event`

```
    if Assigned(FRawSMBIOSData.SMBIOSTableData) then
    begin
      ZeroMemory(FRawSMBIOSData.SMBIOSTableData,FRawSMBIOSData.Length);
      FreeMem(FRawSMBIOSData.SMBIOSTableData);
    end;
```

it working great with `GetSystemFirmwareTable` API code in SMBios but in WMI it removes some memory but still i can find few blocks

wondering why after calling object.free or freeandnil the used memory not released

any idea how to force the application to free it ?

Comment: What you are doing is correct. When you call free, the delphi calls just calls Freemem. It does not zero out memory. Your best bet is using/modifying the memory manager to include this behaviour.

Comment: With [`FastMM`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) you can set `{$define AlwaysClearFreedMemory}` option to clear freed memory. It comes with a performance hit though.

Comment: thanks whosrdaddy and LU RD, i will try FastMM

Comment: If your users are hackers, they'd snapshot the memory while TSMBios is still alive. If they are not - they won't be able to look into the memory anyway.  If you really need it - modify the TSMBios  implementation instead. And all your procedures working with it too -  for example never put serial numbers to strings. If you still hope to put in on heap mgr to conceal your traces - then don't do it globally. Set your custom FreeMem hook that would wipe the memory before calling the old routine. Set thus hook before reading the BIOS and remove it after done, it would be slow mode in between

Comment: You are wasting your time. If you can read the info, so can anyone else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ario 'The ,, i'm using this IDs to ban someusers, i know they can put breakpoints while the object still alive but if they knew what IDs i use they will fake it easly before sending to server ,, so i'm just trying to make it harder

Comment: If they can run code on the machine they can run the same code as you and they can inject debug and modify your code.

Comment: Pay for sentinel hasp keys. They are very dizzy and sometimes do not work for no reasons. But at least they have much better knowledge of protection than you or me.

Comment: Karim, they would not seek "which ID makes my program banned". They would seek "which if-then-else makes my program close rather than work"  and when found will just remove that line to make program work anyway. The ID checking function might cry "foul!" as much as it please - the rest of program would just have no ears to hear it. Did you ever cracked the programs yourself?

Comment: @Arioch'The my program is client/server application , the client send the login data including machine ids and the server side checks the ban list ,, from the client i use Virtualizer on my getmachineid function  ,, also i did some time tricks anti-breakpoints/debuggers to detect if users paused the app to edit the memory with some checksums in many places ,, the main problem is harddisk serials easy to spoof with small tools , MAC easier without tools , drive serials , UUID , everything is changable now without cracking the exe ,

Comment: I just would run your app from VirtualBox then  from day 1 :-D why not ban the user himself instead of his machine that he can change?

Comment: but if your program really is worth it, invest into hardware or at least software HASP and play challenge-response game over random data

Comment: @Arioch'The i can detect virtual machines easly , its chat software and users can join as guests without registration , i don't have problems to pay for any tool if it will provide fairly unchangeable unique id

Comment: then your goal seems to be very unusual... hopefully you do save windows installation SID and user SID... Also I wonder if windows-update has a unique ID for computer, but probably not. Also I wonder if you can tigger fake login in browser... https://panopticlick.eff.org/faq.php Actually you really maybe try to learn from black hats how they spy for users and distinguish them ? list of e-mail accounts, list of installed software, whatever. Your problem I think is not in finding a holy grail that can't be changed like intel cpu id, but combining a 1000 changeable IDs with probability theory

Comment: @Arioch Sentinel know nothing about security, their products are terrible, and they demand royalties, a cut of their customers' profits. They are the lowest of the low.

Comment: @Arioch'The thx for this helpful tips , combining 1000 a changable IDs  will give unique ID but if 1 of the 1000 changed the whole ID will be changed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have a better alternative ?

Comment: better alternative to what?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i didn't found suitable solution on Sentinel , also as u said they know nothing about security , so i'm asking if u know suitable product for what i'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. Question asks about clearing memory.

Comment: Karim,  a probability theory. If one id of thousand changed,  then most probably the computer is the same,  just update your records of it.  If 999 ids of thousand differ -  that probably is another box. Clustering, data mining,  audience targeting...  That all goes from probabilities and statistics.

Comment: @Arioch'The aha i got it now , will work on it :) , thx for ur help

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there might be different contracts, but we just purchase keys for fixed prices. It is not paying royalties in my eyes. Their software sucks, if they would not purchase Alladin, maybe it would be better. But there probably is not too much market for HASP-like tokens and they had to merge. It just is a really niche product, and it is totally outside of Kerim's niche.

Comment: @Arioch Buy HASP4 keys that way. The new tech is royalty based. Everything about that company sucks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan crap! sooner or later they'd cease the support of old tokens in drivers, and new Windows versions would make old drivers suffer of bit rot (it already happened).Are there other companies with similar kind of tokens and EXE crypto-envelopes ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes there are. Personally I'd go for SW licensing because it is so much more convenient for the user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wonder what they are then. In our niche sw licensing would not work. The clients are expected to install program on any boxes without reporting to us. There'd be no online "installation counter" (which personally I think I much worse than tokens)

Comment: @Arioch'The The tokens are soft. I believe that it does allow you to limit the number of concurrent users. Obviously it's easily cracked but then so are hardware keys.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the user runs software at three notebooks, all of those are offline. How your software key would detect concurrent use ? Then, remember DeCSS, it was software DVD player, which leaked the deciphering key, not hardware players.

Comment: @Arioch'The In that case the hardware key wins.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's why your observation is rather sad for our distant future, but thanks for giving alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory is released,  it is just not wiped. You maybe mistake two concepts:  the memory is bound to some owner and cannot be given to another one,  and memory is cleansed of all the information.

Look,  when you go over fresh snow or over sands, you leave your footsteps behind you. You moved away, so the places you've been through are FREE now for anyone else to occupy. But your footsteps remain there until someone would overwrite them with his own ones.

Now,  you may be paranoid and after every step you would turn back,  take a brush and remove your fresh footstep. That is possible and might make sense, but it might be painfully slow.

Some objects might deal with sensitive data, like passwords,  cipher keys, personal data in mass calculations,  etc. For those objects there is the sense to be paranoid and brush out every their trace. So those objects are written in a way to wipe the memory they would no more need immediately after last use. And to do it once again in the destructor.

But when you just closed the form with the message like "file saved successfully" there ain't any secrets worth painting over. And that is the most of the program.

So now please decide if you really have some sensitive data like passwords. If you do - your code should overwrite it with different data before freeing. And you would have to learn how the data is kept for different types in Delphi,  so pieces of the data would not be copied in other places of memory during your processing of them. But most probably you don't need the data actually destroyed, you only need to mark "this place is FREE for anyone to put their data over my garbage"  and that is what freeing object on Delphi actually does. If that is enough for you just don't you bother to wipe the data (which is substituting random garbage instead of sensitive garbage, but a garbage still).

Now,  few words about suggestions of LU RD and whosrdaddy. Yes,  Delphi provides you means to hook into the way heap is managed and to explicitly wipe the data with garbage before marking the apartment free. However this is only a partial solution for sensitive data.

- 99,9% of times you would be clearing data that was not worth it.  Strings,  dynamic arrays,  TList and other containers would be slow - and your program too.
- your app consists of procedures, that have local variables. Many of those variables, like Short Strings,  fixed size arrays,  GUIDs, are allocated on stack rather than in heap. Those suggestions would not clean them,  only free.
- your objects typically allocate memory in Delphi heap.  But they might also allocate it otherwise. In Windows heap,  in some multithreading-aware pool,  or whatever. That memory would not be wiped modifying default Delphi heap manager behavior.

Overall it is the same idea.  Your procedure or your object knows which data is dangerous and where it is kept  - that object or procedure is responsible of cleansing. Global Delphi-scale solutions would be both ineffective and unreliable.